# Encountering "ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)" error when I ran modified litecoin chainparams.cpp

Tags: c++, linux, bitcoin

First: I am a newbite to altcoin development, next to generate an altcoin from litecoin, 
1- I have made a clone of litecoin using `git clone https://githubcom/litecoin-project/lotecoin.git`

2- I changed some of chain and coin parameters in chainparams.cpp as below:

```
 // Copyright (c) 2010 Satoshi Nakamoto
 // Copyright (c) 2009-2015 The Bitcoin Core developers
 // Distributed under the MIT software license, see the accompanying
 // file COPYING or http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php.

 #include "chainparams.h"
 #include "consensus/merkle.h"

 #include "tinyformat.h"
 #include "util.h"
 #include "utilstrencodings.h"

 #include <assert.h>

 #include "chainparamsseeds.h"
 #include "arith_uint256.h"

 static CBlock CreateGenesisBlock(const char* pszTimestamp, const CScript& genesisOutputScript, uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nNonce, uint32_t nBits, int32_t nVersion, const CAmount& genesisReward)
 {
     CMutableTransaction txNew;
     txNew.nVersion = 1;
     txNew.vin.resize(1);
     txNew.vout.resize(1);
     txNew.vin[0].scriptSig = CScript() << 486604799 << CScriptNum(4) << std::vector<unsigned char>((const unsigned char*)pszTimestamp, (const unsigned char*)pszTimestamp + strlen(pszTimestamp));
     txNew.vout[0].nValue = genesisReward;
     txNew.vout[0].scriptPubKey = genesisOutputScript;

     CBlock genesis;
     genesis.nTime    = nTime;
     genesis.nBits    = nBits;
     genesis.nNonce   = nNonce;
     genesis.nVersion = nVersion;
     genesis.vtx.push_back(MakeTransactionRef(std::move(txNew)));
     genesis.hashPrevBlock.SetNull();
     genesis.hashMerkleRoot = BlockMerkleRoot(genesis);
     return genesis;
 }

 /**
  * Build the genesis block. Note that the output of its generation
  * transaction cannot be spent since it did not originally exist in the
  * database.
  *
  * CBlock(hash=000000000019d6, ver=1, hashPrevBlock=00000000000000, hashMerkleRoot=4a5e1e, nTime=1231006505, nBits=1d00ffff, *nNonce=2083236893, vtx=1)
  *   CTransaction(hash=4a5e1e, ver=1, vin.size=1, vout.size=1, nLockTime=0)
  *     CTxIn(COutPoint(000000, -1), coinbase *04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e206272696e6b206f66207365636f6e64206261696c6f757420**666f722062616e6b73)
  *     CTxOut(nValue=50.00000000, scriptPubKey=0x5F1DF16B2B704C8A578D0B)
  *   vMerkleTree: 4a5e1e
  */

 static CBlock CreateGenesisBlock(uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nNonce, uint32_t nBits, int32_t nVersion, const CAmount& genesisReward)
 {
     const char* pszTimestamp = "Tehran Times, Stonica wins finally";
     const CScript genesisOutputScript = CScript() << ParseHex("040184710fa689ad5023690c80f3a49c8f13f8d45b8c857fbcbc8bc4a8e4d3eb4b10f4d4604fa08dce601aaf0f470216fe1b51850b4acf21b179c45070ac7b03a9") << OP_CHECKSIG;
     return CreateGenesisBlock(pszTimestamp, genesisOutputScript, nTime, nNonce, nBits, nVersion, genesisReward);
 }

 void CChainParams::UpdateVersionBitsParameters(Consensus::DeploymentPos d, int64_t nStartTime, int64_t nTimeout)
 {
     consensus.vDeployments[d].nStartTime = nStartTime;
     consensus.vDeployments[d].nTimeout = nTimeout;
 }

 /**
  * Main network
  */
 /**
  * What makes a good checkpoint block?
  * + Is surrounded by blocks with reasonable timestamps
  *   (no blocks before with a timestamp after, none after with
  *    timestamp before)
  * + Contains no strange transactions
  */

 class CMainParams : public CChainParams {
 public:
     CMainParams() {
         strNetworkID = "main";
         consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 840000;
         consensus.BIP34Height = 710000;
         consensus.BIP34Hash = uint256S("00000000b2c50d03d4d0bdd38681775ce522f137518145d6b3c913b7dd4423e5");
         consensus.BIP65Height = 918684; // bab3041e8977e0dc3eeff63fe707b92bde1dd449d8efafb248c27c8264cc311a
         consensus.BIP66Height = 811879; // 7aceee012833fa8952f8835d8b1b3ae233cd6ab08fdb27a771d2bd7bdc491894
         consensus.powLimit = uint256S("00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"); 
         consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 3.5 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3.5 days
         consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 2.5 * 60;
         consensus.fPowAllowMinDifficultyBlocks = false;
         consensus.fPowNoRetargeting = false;
         consensus.nRuleChangeActivationThreshold = 6048; // 75% of 8064
         consensus.nMinerConfirmationWindow = 8064; // nPowTargetTimespan / nPowTargetSpacing * 4
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].bit = 28;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nStartTime = 1199145601; // January 1, 2008
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nTimeout = 1230767999; // December 31, 2008

         // Deployment of BIP68, BIP112, and BIP113.
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].bit = 0;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nStartTime = 1485561600; // January 28, 2017
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

         // Deployment of SegWit (BIP141, BIP143, and BIP147)
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].bit = 1;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nStartTime = 1485561600; // January 28, 2017
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

         // The best chain should have at least this much work.
         consensus.nMinimumChainWork = uint256S("0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ba50a60f8b56c7fe0");

         // By default assume that the signatures in ancestors of this block are valid.
         consensus.defaultAssumeValid = uint256S("0x29c8c00e1a5f446a6364a29633d3f1ee16428d87c8d3851a1c570be8170b04c2"); //1259849

         /**
          * The message start string is designed to be unlikely to occur in normal data.
          * The characters are rarely used upper ASCII, not valid as UTF-8, and produce
          * a large 32-bit integer with any alignment.
          */
         pchMessageStart[0] = 0x0b;
         pchMessageStart[1] = 0xd0;
         pchMessageStart[2] = 0xb6;
         pchMessageStart[3] = 0xdb;
         nDefaultPort = 9335;
         nPruneAfterHeight = 100000;
 //static CBlock CreateGenesisBlock(uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nNonce, uint32_t nBits, int32_t nVersion, const CAmount& genesisReward)
         genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1511279793, 1251189192, 0x1d00ffff , 1, 50 * COIN);
         consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();

 /*        
         // calculate Genesis Block
         // Reset genesis
         consensus.hashGenesisBlock = uint256S("0x");
         std::cout << std::string("Begin calculating Mainnet Genesis Block:\n");
         if (true && (genesis.GetHash() != consensus.hashGenesisBlock)) {
             LogPrintf("Calculating Mainnet Genesis Block:\n");
             arith_uint256 hashTarget = arith_uint256().SetCompact(genesis.nBits);
             uint256 hash;
             genesis.nNonce = 0;
             // This will figure out a valid hash and Nonce if you're
             // creating a different genesis block:
             // uint256 hashTarget = CBigNum().SetCompact(genesis.nBits).getuint256();
             // hashTarget.SetCompact(genesis.nBits, &fNegative, &fOverflow).getuint256();
             // while (genesis.GetHash() > hashTarget)
             while (UintToArith256(genesis.GetHash()) > hashTarget)
             {
                 ++genesis.nNonce;
                 if (genesis.nNonce == 0)
                 {
                     LogPrintf("NONCE WRAPPED, incrementing time");
                     std::cout << std::string("NONCE WRAPPED, incrementing time:\n");
                     ++genesis.nTime;
                 }
                 if (genesis.nNonce % 10000 == 0)
                 {
                     LogPrintf("Mainnet: nonce %08u: hash = %s \n", genesis.nNonce, genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str());
                     // std::cout << strNetworkID << " nonce: " << genesis.nNonce << " time: " << genesis.nTime << " hash: " << genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str() << "\n";
                 }
             }
             std::cout << "Mainnet ---\n";
             std::cout << "  nonce: " << genesis.nNonce <<  "\n";
             std::cout << "   time: " << genesis.nTime << "\n";
             std::cout << "   hash: " << genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str() << "\n";
             std::cout << "   merklehash: "  << genesis.hashMerkleRoot.ToString().c_str() << "\n";
             // Mainnet --- nonce: 296277 time: 1390095618 hash: 000000bdd771b14e5a031806292305e563956ce2584278de414d9965f6ab54b0
         }
         std::cout << std::string("Finished calculating Mainnet Genesis Block:\n");


 */





 //printf("%s\n",consensus.hashGenesisBlock.Tostring().c_str());
  std::cout << std::string("ENTER:\n");
        assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x00000000b2c50d03d4d0bdd38681775ce522f137518145d6b3c913b7dd4423e5"));
         assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0xf8621e34b0dcd43361fe589702e06aa79992229bfbca57d058d8561635c30fbe"));
     std::cout << std::string("PASSED:\n");

         printf("min nBit:  %08x\n", consensus.powLimit);

         // Note that of those with the service bits flag, most only support a subset of possible options
         //vSeeds.emplace_back("seed-a.stonicacoin.loshan.co.uk", true);
         //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.thrasher.io", true);
         //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.stonicacointools.com", true);
         //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.stonicacoinpool.org", true);
         //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.koin-project.com", false);

         base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,127);
         base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,65);
         base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS2] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,56);
         base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] =     std::vector<unsigned char>(1,176);
         base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xB2, 0x1E};
         base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xAD, 0xE4};

         vFixedSeeds = std::vector<SeedSpec6>(pnSeed6_main, pnSeed6_main + ARRAYLEN(pnSeed6_main));

         fDefaultConsistencyChecks = false;
         fRequireStandard = true;
         fMineBlocksOnDemand = false;

         checkpointData = (CCheckpointData) {
             {
                 {  0, uint256S("0x00000000b2c50d03d4d0bdd38681775ce522f137518145d6b3c913b7dd4423e5")},

             }
         };

         chainTxData = ChainTxData{
             // Data as of block db42d00d824950a125f9b08b6b6c282c484781562fa8b3bd29d6ce4a2627c348 (height 1259851).
             1502955334, // * UNIX timestamp of last known number of transactions
             1,  // * total number of transactions between genesis and that timestamp
                     //   (the tx=... number in the SetBestChain debug.log lines)
             0.00     // * estimated number of transactions per second after that timestamp
         };
     }
 };

 /**
  * Testnet (v3)
  */
 class CTestNetParams : public CChainParams {
 public:
     CTestNetParams() {
         strNetworkID = "test";
         consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 840000;
         consensus.BIP34Height = 76;
         consensus.BIP34Hash = uint256S("8075c771ed8b495ffd943980a95f702ab34fce3c8c54e379548bda33cc8c0573");
         consensus.BIP65Height = 76; // 8075c771ed8b495ffd943980a95f702ab34fce3c8c54e379548bda33cc8c0573
         consensus.BIP66Height = 76; // 8075c771ed8b495ffd943980a95f702ab34fce3c8c54e379548bda33cc8c0573
         consensus.powLimit = uint256S("00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
         consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 3.5 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3.5 days
         consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 2.5 * 60;
         consensus.fPowAllowMinDifficultyBlocks = true;
         consensus.fPowNoRetargeting = false;
         consensus.nRuleChangeActivationThreshold = 1512; // 75% for testchains
         consensus.nMinerConfirmationWindow = 2016; // nPowTargetTimespan / nPowTargetSpacing
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].bit = 28;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nStartTime = 1199145601; // January 1, 2008
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nTimeout = 1230767999; // December 31, 2008

         // Deployment of BIP68, BIP112, and BIP113.
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].bit = 0;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nStartTime = 1483228800; // January 1, 2017
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

         // Deployment of SegWit (BIP141, BIP143, and BIP147)
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].bit = 1;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nStartTime = 1483228800; // January 1, 2017
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

         // The best chain should have at least this much work.
         consensus.nMinimumChainWork = uint256S("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000364b0cbc3568");

         // By default assume that the signatures in ancestors of this block are valid.
         consensus.defaultAssumeValid = uint256S("0xad8ff6c2f5580d2b50bd881e11312425ea84fa99f322bf132beb722f97971bba"); //153490

         pchMessageStart[0] = 0xfd;
         pchMessageStart[1] = 0xd2;
         pchMessageStart[2] = 0xc8;
         pchMessageStart[3] = 0xf1;
         nDefaultPort = 19335;
         nPruneAfterHeight = 1000;

         genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1511279793, 0, 0x1d00ffff , 1, 50 * COIN);
         consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();
         //assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x"));
         //assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0x"));

         vFixedSeeds.clear();
         vSeeds.clear();
         // nodes with support for servicebits filtering should be at the top
         //vSeeds.emplace_back("testnet-seed.stonicacointools.com", true);
         //vSeeds.emplace_back("seed-b.stonicacoin.loshan.co.uk", true);
         //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed-testnet.thrasher.io", true);

         base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,111);
         base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,196);
         base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS2] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,58);
         base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] =     std::vector<unsigned char>(1,239);
         base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = {0x04, 0x35, 0x87, 0xCF};
         base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = {0x04, 0x35, 0x83, 0x94};

         vFixedSeeds = std::vector<SeedSpec6>(pnSeed6_test, pnSeed6_test + ARRAYLEN(pnSeed6_test));

         fDefaultConsistencyChecks = false;
         fRequireStandard = false;
         fMineBlocksOnDemand = false;

         checkpointData = (CCheckpointData) {
             {
                 {0, uint256S("")},
             }
         };

         chainTxData = ChainTxData{
             // Data as of block 3351b6229da00b47ad7a8d7e1323b0e2874744b5296e3d6448293463ab758624 (height 153489)
             //1502953751,
             //382986,
             //0.01
         };

     }
 };

 /**
  * Regression test
  */
 class CRegTestParams : public CChainParams {
 public:
     CRegTestParams() {
         strNetworkID = "regtest";
         consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 150;
         consensus.BIP34Height = 100000000; // BIP34 has not activated on regtest (far in the future so block v1 are not rejected in tests)
         consensus.BIP34Hash = uint256();
         consensus.BIP65Height = 1351; // BIP65 activated on regtest (Used in rpc activation tests)
         consensus.BIP66Height = 1251; // BIP66 activated on regtest (Used in rpc activation tests)
         consensus.powLimit = uint256S("7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
         consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 3.5 * 24 * 60 * 60; // two weeks
         consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 2.5 * 60;
         consensus.fPowAllowMinDifficultyBlocks = true;
         consensus.fPowNoRetargeting = true;
         consensus.nRuleChangeActivationThreshold = 108; // 75% for testchains
         consensus.nMinerConfirmationWindow = 144; // Faster than normal for regtest (144 instead of 2016)
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].bit = 28;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nStartTime = 0;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nTimeout = 999999999999ULL;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].bit = 0;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nStartTime = 0;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nTimeout = 999999999999ULL;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].bit = 1;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nStartTime = 0;
         consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nTimeout = 999999999999ULL;

         // The best chain should have at least this much work.
         consensus.nMinimumChainWork = uint256S("0x00");

         // By default assume that the signatures in ancestors of this block are valid.
         consensus.defaultAssumeValid = uint256S("0x00");

         pchMessageStart[0] = 0xfa;
         pchMessageStart[1] = 0xbf;
         pchMessageStart[2] = 0xb5;
         pchMessageStart[3] = 0xda;
         nDefaultPort = 19444;
         nPruneAfterHeight = 1000;

         genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1511279793, 0, 0x1d00ffff , 1, 50 * COIN);
         consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();
         assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x9"));
         assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0x"));

         vFixedSeeds.clear(); //!< Regtest mode doesn't have any fixed seeds.
         vSeeds.clear();      //!< Regtest mode doesn't have any DNS seeds.

         fDefaultConsistencyChecks = true;
         fRequireStandard = false;
         fMineBlocksOnDemand = true; 

         checkpointData = (CCheckpointData) {
             {
                 {0, uint256S("530827f38f93b43ed12af0b3ad25a288dc02ed74d6d7857862df51fc56c416f9")},
             }
         };

         chainTxData = ChainTxData{
             0,
             0,
             0
         };

         base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,111);
         base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,196);
         base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS2] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,58);
         base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] =     std::vector<unsigned char>(1,239);
         base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = {0x04, 0x35, 0x87, 0xCF};
         base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = {0x04, 0x35, 0x83, 0x94};
     }
 };

 static std::unique_ptr<CChainParams> globalChainParams;

 const CChainParams &Params() {
     assert(globalChainParams);
     return *globalChainParams;
 }

 std::unique_ptr<CChainParams> CreateChainParams(const std::string& chain)
 {
     if (chain == CBaseChainParams::MAIN)
         return std::unique_ptr<CChainParams>(new CMainParams());
     else if (chain == CBaseChainParams::TESTNET)
         return std::unique_ptr<CChainParams>(new CTestNetParams());
     else if (chain == CBaseChainParams::REGTEST)
         return std::unique_ptr<CChainParams>(new CRegTestParams());
     throw std::runtime_error(strprintf("%s: Unknown chain %s.", __func__, chain));
 }

 void SelectParams(const std::string& network)
 {
     SelectBaseParams(network);
     globalChainParams = CreateChainParams(network);
 }

 void UpdateVersionBitsParameters(Consensus::DeploymentPos d, int64_t nStartTime, int64_t nTimeout)
 {
     globalChainParams->UpdateVersionBitsParameters(d, nStartTime, nTimeout);
 }
```

As you may know the bitcoin developers has omitted the genesis block mining code from source code published in github, but I fortunately found some piece of code in related blogs and it worked, then I have calculated the new Genesis hash, Merkelroot hash and Nonce and put into code as you can see above.
The code was compiled correctly and I have not received Assertion failed message for Genesis block but I received another error which you can see in debug.log as below:

```
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 



















 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Stonicacoin version v0.15.0.1-gba8ed3a93be
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Assuming ancestors of block 29c8c00e1a5f446a6364a29633d3f1ee16428d87c8d3851a1c570be8170b04c2 have valid signatures.
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using the 'standard' SHA256 implementation
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using RdRand as an additional entropy source
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Default data directory /home/kevin/.stonicacoin
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using data directory /home/kevin/.stonicacoin
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using config file /home/kevin/.stonicacoin/stonicacoin.conf
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using at most 125 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using 8 threads for script verification
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 scheduler thread start
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 No rpcpassword set - using random cookie authentication
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Generated RPC authentication cookie /home/kevin/.stonicacoin/.cookie
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Cache configuration:
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 * Using 440.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 4.8MiB of unused mempool space)
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 init message: Loading block index...
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Opening LevelDB in /home/kevin/.stonicacoin/blocks/index
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Opened LevelDB successfully
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using obfuscation key for /home/kevin/.stonicacoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 0
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=0, size=0, heights=0...0, time=1970-01-01...1970-01-01)
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Checking all blk files are present...
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 LoadBlockIndexDB: transaction index disabled
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Initializing databases...
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Pre-allocating up to position 0x1000000 in blk00000.dat
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Opening LevelDB in /home/kevin/.stonicacoin/chainstate
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Opened LevelDB successfully
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Wrote new obfuscate key for /home/kevin/.stonicacoin/chainstate: 77f259e28117a4e1
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Using obfuscation key for /home/kevin/.stonicacoin/chainstate: 77f259e28117a4e1
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 init message: Rewinding blocks...
 2017-12-15 07:31:33  block index              11ms
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 No wallet support compiled in!
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 *** Failed to read block
 2017-12-15 07:31:33 Error: Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
```

I found that this error(eg. ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8) )  occur in CheckProofOfWork function which is in pow.cpp, Any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: did you solve it?? I have the same problem

Comment: I met same problem here.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling too much I finally solve the issue:

1)

```
consensus.powLimit = uint256S("00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
```

should be set to a lower limit like

```
consensus.powLimit = uint256S("00ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
```

and set genesis.nBits to 0x1f00ffff when in CreateGenesisBlock function like

```
genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1519394018, 6446, 0x1f0fffff, 1, 1 * COIN);
```

For Testnet I used 0x1f0fffff.

2) For Bitcoin v0.15+ the following genesis block generating code should be used:

```
    // calculate Genesis Block
        // Reset genesis
        consensus.hashGenesisBlock = uint256S("0x");
        std::cout << std::string("Begin calculating Mainnet Genesis Block:\n");
        if (true && (genesis.GetHash(consensus) != consensus.hashGenesisBlock)) {
//                     LogPrintf("Calculating Mainnet Genesis Block:\n");
            arith_uint256 hashTarget = arith_uint256().SetCompact(genesis.nBits);
            uint256 hash;
            genesis.nNonce = ArithToUint256(0);
            while (UintToArith256(genesis.GetHash(consensus)) > hashTarget)
            {
                genesis.nNonce = ArithToUint256(UintToArith256(genesis.nNonce) + 1);
                         if (genesis.nNonce == ArithToUint256(arith_uint256(0)))
                         {
                             LogPrintf("NONCE WRAPPED, incrementing time");
                             std::cout << std::string("NONCE WRAPPED, incrementing time:\n");
                             ++genesis.nTime;
                         }

                         if ((int)genesis.nNonce.GetUint64(0) % 10000 == 0)
                         {
                              std::cout << strNetworkID << " hashTarget: " << hashTarget.ToString() << " nonce: " << genesis.nNonce.ToString() << " time: " << genesis.nTime << " hash: " << genesis.GetHash(consensus).ToString().c_str() << "\r";
                         }

            }
                     std::cout << "Mainnet ---\n";
                     std::cout << "  nonce: " << genesis.nNonce.ToString() <<  "\n";
                     std::cout << "   time: " << genesis.nTime << "\n";
                     std::cout << "   hash: " << genesis.GetHash(consensus).ToString().c_str() << "\n";
                     std::cout << "   merklehash: "  << genesis.hashMerkleRoot.ToString().c_str() << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << std::string("Finished calculating Mainnet Genesis Block:\n");
```

For the older codebases the genesis block generating code that @Hossein Mirheydari given is working. Actually you should check

```
genesis.nNonce   = ArithToUint256(arith_uint256(nNonce));
```

definition in

```
static CBlock CreateGenesisBlock(const char* pszTimestamp, const CScript& genesisOutputScript, uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nNonce, uint32_t nBits, int32_t nVersion, const CAmount& genesisReward);
```

function to see if it's given as above or as

```
genesis.nNonce   = nNonce;
```

If it's given as the latter one then use @Hossein Mirheydari's genesis block generation code. If it's given with ArithToUint256() function use the genesis block generation code I pasted above.

3) This genesis block generation should be done for Mainnet and Testnet seperately. Regtest does not need a genesis block generation since it's pow limit is so small (but you may want to do it anyway just to be sure of everything works fine) and so

```
printf("TEST GENESIS HASH: %s\n",consensus.hashGenesisBlock.ToString().c_str());
printf("TEST MERKLE ROOT: %s\n",genesis.hashMerkleRoot.ToString().c_str());
assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x0009b0d830d5e13f7a39dd6c30cae59ff95e1a4aa4fc22435dc1fcb92561cd8e"));
assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0xf1552bf3d58facdc6d7ec8461aff6b0560d20eb16e41749b9f8f5a7eaa1220fc"));
```

inserting the printed consensus.hashGenesisBlock and genesis.hashMerkleRoot into

```
assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x0009b0d830d5e13f7a39dd6c30cae59ff95e1a4aa4fc22435dc1fcb92561cd8e"));
assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0xf1552bf3d58facdc6d7ec8461aff6b0560d20eb16e41749b9f8f5a7eaa1220fc"));
```

statements works.

4) If you have

```
    consensus.powLimitStart = uint256S("0000000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
    consensus.powLimitLegacy = uint256S("00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
```

like the ones in Bitcoin Gold (which I now am using) use the same pow limit as consensus.powLimit.

Thus, with genesis generation code, genesis block is generated. With low pow limit, genesis block be in pow range and so no PoW validation error will occur anymore.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks you so much!! I am now trying to cloning litecoin's newest source, so I will test this today, and will send you message. Please add me skype : leegodskype

Comment: Tested, but, hm... I got still this error. 
-------
2018-02-26 04:50:02 ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)
2018-02-26 04:50:02 *** Failed to read block
2018-02-26 04:50:02 Error: Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see debug.log for details
------
So I used @Hossein's genesis block generation code because in CreateGenesisBlock, genesis.nNonce = nNonce;  like this defined. What now?... hm...

Comment: And what should be value of this variable after ParseHex(?)

const CScript genesisOutputScript = CScript() << ParseHex("04dfx.............................) << OP_CHECKSIG;

Comment: So maybe it need to pass genesis valid check? at pow.cpp's "CheckProofOfWork" function.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDGxGYvkDEE&t=12s this video (and the following 5 videos in the series) helped me a lot. It will answer most of your questions i believe. It also tells how to create the value given to ParseHex() (it's an ssl privkey+pubkey creation). I would rather use Bitcoin v0.16 (released today) rather than litecoin codebase. The genesis block creation is in chainparams.cpp file in bitcoin client and it's not very different. You can use grep or other search tool to find the other variables in the code.

Comment: Yes I know those videos, I already saw them all. Problem is, that is based on version 0.8  So I want to clone newest source.

Comment: So I am now stuck at how make genesis block pass valid test (function, CheckProofOfWork  in pow.cpp), I tried to use this function in chainparams.cpp (of course with #include pow.h), but got error when trying compile. Maybe link error is this? Then how to make it work...

Comment: And why you rather use bitcoin 0.16 than litecoin source? Just curious.

Comment: It's the most recent release with all bugs fixed and it uses more recent libraries which came with the recent releases of Linux distributions. If you use older version of Bitcoin, then you have to use older versions of Linux distributions with older versions of libraries (like for instance Ubuntu 16.04.3 instead of 17.04 or OpenSUSE Leap 14.2 instead of Tumbleweed) in order maintain the library compatibility. You won't be able to upgrade your distribution or libraries to the newest releases. But the main reason is the security fixes done for the new threats.

Comment: Yes that is good. Then I want to use that too. But why I used litecoin is, isn't Scrypt is more good algorithm than SHA256 which bitcoin uses?

Comment: And after adopt your script, bunch of compile errors. First, genesis.GetHash(consensus)  this seems not acceptable, says 'no matching function for call to 'CBlock::GetHash(Consensus::Params&)'

Comment: And paste this generation code twice to mainnet and testnet part each?

Answer (score 1):

On the `main` branch at this time the solution for me was to change the `GetHash()` to `GetPoWHash()`. I also followed the answer of @Bedri Ozgur Guler for the PoWLimit and nBits:

```cpp
consensus.hashGenesisBlock = uint256S("0x");
std::cout << std::string("Begin calculating Mainnet Genesis Block:\n");
  if (true && (genesis.GetHash() != consensus.hashGenesisBlock)) {
    LogPrintf("Calculating Mainnet Genesis Block:\n");
    arith_uint256 hashTarget = arith_uint256().SetCompact(genesis.nBits);
    uint256 hash;
    genesis.nNonce = 0;

    while (UintToArith256(genesis.GetPoWHash()) > hashTarget) // ---> Here GetPoWHash() !!
    {
      ++genesis.nNonce;
      if (genesis.nNonce == 0)
      {
        LogPrintf("NONCE WRAPPED, incrementing time");
        std::cout << std::string("NONCE WRAPPED, incrementing time:\n");
        ++genesis.nTime;
      }
                 
      if (genesis.nNonce % 10000 == 0)
      {
        LogPrintf("Mainnet: nonce %08u: hash = %s \n", genesis.nNonce, genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str());
        // std::cout << strNetworkID << " nonce: " << genesis.nNonce << " time: " << genesis.nTime << " hash: " << genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str() << "\n";
      }
    }
    
    std::cout << "Mainnet ---\n";
    std::cout << "  nonce: " << genesis.nNonce <<  "\n";
    std::cout << "   time: " << genesis.nTime << "\n";
    std::cout << "   hash: " << genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str() << "\n"; // The hash for the assert is GetHash()
    std::cout << "   merklehash: "  << genesis.hashMerkleRoot.ToString().c_str() << "\n";
    // Mainnet --- nonce: 296277 time: 1390095618 hash: 000000bdd771b14e5a031806292305e563956ce2584278de414d9965f6ab54b0
  }
  std::cout << std::string("Finished calculating Mainnet Genesis Block:\n");
```

Looking in the file `validation.cpp` on the method `ReadBlockFromDisk` I found that the hash that must pass the `CheckProofOfWork` is the **PoWHash**

```cpp
bool ReadBlockFromDisk(CBlock& block, const CDiskBlockPos& pos, const Consensus::Params& consensusParams) 
{
    // ...
    // Check the header
    if (!CheckProofOfWork(block.GetPoWHash(), block.nBits, consensusParams))
        return error("ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at %s", pos.ToString());
}
```

**EDIT**: Tested with the litecoin PoWLimit and nBits values and It worked.

```cpp
consensus.powLimit = uint256S("00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1619494752, 721332, 0x1e0ffff0, 1, 50 * COIN);
```

Answer (score 0):

FreddyJS, `genesis.GetPoWHash()` worked nicely for litecoin, the hashes match what I would get with GenesisH0. But unfortunately it doesn't work on another coin I'm testing, gives an error on compilation. Any ideas?

`error: no matching function for call to ‘CBlock::GetPoWHash()’`

After some digging, the code is different than litecoin. In validation.cpp:

```
    // Check the header
    if (!CheckProofOfWork(block.GetPoWHash(nHeight), block.nBits, consensusParams))
        return error("ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at %s, %d", pos.ToString(), nHeight);
```

`GetPoWHash(nHeight)` vs `GetPoWHash()` in litecoin.

Answer (score 0):

This is code of Raptoreum

```
https://github.com/Raptor3um/raptoreum/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp
```

Them try debug Dash to find genesis block hash

Them change only Time

```
static CBlock CreateGenesisBlock(uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nNonce, uint32_t nBits, int32_t nVersion, const CAmount& genesisReward)
{
    const char* pszTimestamp = "The Times 22/Jan/2018 Raptoreum is name of the game for new generation of firms";
    const CScript genesisOutputScript = CScript() << ParseHex("040184710fa689ad5023690c80f3a49c8f13f8d45b8c857fbcbc8bc4a8e4d3eb4b10f4d4604fa08dce601aaf0f470216fe1b51850b4acf21b179c45070ac7b03a9") << OP_CHECKSIG;
    return CreateGenesisBlock(pszTimestamp, genesisOutputScript, nTime, nNonce, nBits, nVersion, genesisReward);
}
```

The Dask use X11

```
###
static void FindMainNetGenesisBlock(uint32_t nTime, uint32_t nBits, const char* network)
{

    CBlock block = CreateGenesisBlock(nTime, 0, nBits, 4, 5000 * COIN);

    arith_uint256 bnTarget;
    bnTarget.SetCompact(block.nBits);

    for (uint32_t nNonce = 0; nNonce < UINT32_MAX; nNonce++) {
        block.nNonce = nNonce;

        uint256 hash = block.GetPOWHash();
        if (nNonce % 48 == 0) {
            printf("\nrnonce=%d, pow is %s\n", nNonce, hash.GetHex().c_str());
        }
        if (UintToArith256(hash) <= bnTarget) {
            printf("\n%s net\n", network);
            printf("\ngenesis is %s\n", block.ToString().c_str());
            printf("\npow is %s\n", hash.GetHex().c_str());
            printf("\ngenesisNonce is %d\n", nNonce);
            std::cout << "Genesis Merkle " << block.hashMerkleRoot.GetHex() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

    }

    // This is very unlikely to happen as we start the devnet with a very low difficulty. In many cases even the first
    // iteration of the above loop will give a result already
    error("%sNetGenesisBlock: could not find %s genesis block",network, network);
    assert(false);
}
###
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems the `-reindex` parameter <s>solves</s> avoids the issue *and gives the main reason of error which is Genesis Block does not have valid PoW*. It is suggested in [BITCOIN CORE CRASHED #8081](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/8081) (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/8081) for a solution for the issue of a corrupted blockchain data:

> [sipa](https://github.com/sipa) commented on 21 May 2016
>   Start bitcoind or bitcoin-qt with
>   the -reindex command line option. This will throw away the indexes and
>   rebuild them from scratch, but reuse the blocks on disk in so far as
>   they are usable.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18716968)

Comment: Link also does not have an explanation of what the cause of the underlying problem is. I had this problem while playing around the codes of groestlcoin and after re-setting variables in the code like nGenesisBlockRewardCoin as well as consensus.hashGenesisBlock and genesis.hashMerkleRoot. I tried to start a brand new chain but got this problem at the end. While not having a deep insight about the nature of the problem, it's obvious that chain and/or wallet corrupted at some point and -reindex or -reindex-chainstate (proposed by debug.log) parameter solves the issue. It's a temporary solution.

Comment: @BedriOzgurGuler HI, I met same this problem of OP, adding -reindex seems at least take me next step, but now debug.log continuously written message of "potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer", do you know why? and what is fundamental solution of your last comment then?

Comment: @leegod You may want to check this issue post on bitcoin github:
[net] Skip stale tip checks in regtest #12484 (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/12484#issuecomment-367707793)
and this: "Potential stale tip detected" when deliberately not connected to peers #11608 (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/11608)

Comment: I am not sure if these two issue threads will help with your case but it worth checking and maybe you can see something helpful for you.

Comment: but then, maybe software does not do anything alone? I need another peer to test genesis block generation and all other features?

Comment: Even after I add -connect=0, debug.log says Potential stale tip detected,,,,